# MailChimp Api 3.0 interest group

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I can't get my group , in create the campaigns

```
 var campaign = Manager.Campaigns.AddAsync(new Campaign
            {
                Settings = _campaignSettings,
                Recipients = new Recipient
                {
                    ListId = ListID,
                    SegmentOptions = new SegmentOptions
                    {
                        Match = Match.Any,
                        Conditions = new List<Condition>
                        {
                            new Condition{Type=ConditionType.Interests ,Field = "interests-bfb01be5fa",Operator = Operator.InterestContains, Value =  "5cde411d26" } 
                        }
                    }
                },
                Type = CampaignType.Regular,
            }).Result;
```

The Picture group doesn't select:
[image]

The Picture i manually selected the group:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a answer .

It work after changed the value

```
Value = new Dictionary<int , string>{ { 1 , "5cde411d26" } } } // If Have two group , can be 2 , "Group ID"
```